# Windows generated blend file compatibility with Mac OSX

Tags: osx

How can I share and make compatible a windows generated blend file to a Mac OSX Blender user?

Comment: .blend files are .blend files, they should just work (at least that's been the case for me).

Answer (score 2):

So far, all .blend files have worked for me no matter on which OS they are created, or on which they are used. Just copy the file over and open it. I've often created it on one, edited it on another, then rendered on yet another.

Comment: Can confirm. I work in a mixed environment (workstation is OSX, render farm is Windows because our studio has a lot of 3DS Max users). No trouble at all going between operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

**Blender files are compatible across platforms**: Linux, Windows and OSX. No need to do anything.

The only thing that changes is how they reference linked files. (backslash \ or forward slash /) and path/disk naming specific to each OS. If you are using packed images/textures and relative paths, the files are transparently used regardless of plattform...

Comment: Apart from absolute paths breaking external files (linked models/images/caches/...), any failure to open a blend file in multiple OS's should be reported as a bug. There is a chance that video textures or VSE strips could use codecs that need extra installation or custom compiled libraries to be usable on some OS's.

Comment: And perhaps it should go without saying: the variation of drive/file/paths and link syntax across these OSes is due to the OS, not to blender specifically. (It's ancient computer history, from the days we modelled with Stone Knives and Bear Skins.)